# SSH connections difficulties

Tags: ssh, rhel, gridengine

I'm using RED HAT 5.9 OS on my grid, having 3 machine:
1 Head node (known as ilmn-qm.ilmn) and 2 compute nodes (aka compute-00-00 and compute-00-01).

**Problem is that i cant use SSH from either one of the compute nodes units.**

I tried:

1) SSH FROM and TO head node works perfectly.

2) SSH from head node to compute nodes works.

3) vise versa SSH from compute nodes to head nodes work as well.

4) Head node define as gateway:

```
[root@compute-00-01 ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.20.22.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.20.20.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
default         ilmn-qm.ilmn    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

5) I've checked that ipv4 forwarding is enabled on the Head node

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf
# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 0

# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

# Controls the use of TCP syncookies
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

and yet any ssh attempt ends up with:

```
ssh: connect to host 132.68.107.69 port 22: Connection timed out
```

from Head node:

```
root@ilmn-qm ~ # ip a show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:0b:2d:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 132.68.106.1/28 brd 132.68.106.15 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::f24d:a2ff:fe0b:2db9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:0b:2d:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.20.5/24 brd 172.20.20.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::f24d:a2ff:fe0b:2dbb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:0b:2d:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.21.2/24 brd 172.20.21.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::f24d:a2ff:fe0b:2dbd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:0b:2d:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
root@ilmn-qm ~ # ip route show
132.68.106.0/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 132.68.106.1
172.20.21.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.21.2
172.20.20.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.20.5
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth2  scope link
default via 132.68.106.14 dev eth0
```

from compute-00-00:

```
[root@compute-00-00 ~]# ip a show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:0b:2d:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.20.6/24 brd 172.20.20.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::f24d:a2ff:fe0b:2dc2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:0b:2d:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.22.6/24 brd 172.20.22.255 scope global eth1
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:0b:2d:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:4d:a2:0b:2d:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
[root@compute-00-00 ~]# ip route show
172.20.22.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.22.6
172.20.20.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.20.6
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link
default via 172.20.20.5 dev eth0
```

from compute-00-01:

```
[root@compute-00-01 ~]# ip a show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:f9:9e:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.20.7/24 brd 172.20.20.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::862b:2bff:fef9:9e11/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:f9:9e:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.22.7/24 brd 172.20.22.255 scope global eth1
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:f9:9e:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:f9:9e:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
[root@compute-00-01 ~]# ip route show
172.20.22.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.22.7
172.20.20.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.20.7
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link
default via 172.20.20.5 dev eth0
```

Comment: Is it possible that the cluster admin has a policy restricting outbound ssh from the compute nodes? I could imagine “compute nodes are for computing, not interacting”

Comment: I have access to compute clusters like these, and access to the actual compute nodes are restricted. You log in on the head node and submit your jobs, and that is all you do. Since projects are billed according to the time spend using the cluster, bypassing the queuing system or interfering with nodes used by others is not something we'd like to see people doing.

Comment: I have administrator permissions. in addition, ssh connection did work until recently.

Comment: Add the IP configuration of all 3 nodes to your question. Are the compute nodes on the same network? Show the output of `ip a show`, `ip route show` on all 3 nodes.

Comment: i edited the post adding the commands

Comment: @wurtel thoughts?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the compute nodes can't ssh outside of the cluster? I thought at first that they couldn't ssh each other. This is probably because you have not setup the head node to NAT the outgoing traffic, so you're trying to send packets to 132.68.107.69 with a source address 172.20.20.6 or .7, which of course won't work.

Comment: What is 132.68.**107**.69? You've got no such network in the configuration you've shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add a SNAT rule to the head node, so that traffic from the compute nodes has the correct source IP address when trying to reach some server on the internet. Sending out packets with a source IP address in the 172.20.20.0/24 range won't work.

You can configure the SNAT like this on your head node:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 172.20.20.0/24 -j SNAT --to 32.68.106.1
```

Comment: that's solved the problem! i do have a question though. it seems now that i'm able to ssh other servers as well, so why is the --to 132.68.107.69 for?

Comment: The `--to` defines to what your source address is mapped to via SNAT, not what the destination is. You should read the `-j SNAT --to 32.68.106.1` as one complete statement.